# Oracle started failed, how to connect RMAN?

Tags: database, oracle, rman

Currently, my Oracle cannot be started up successfully. I executed `startup mount`, it is OK. Then I executed `startup open`. It said

```
Unable to Creating archive log file to '+DGARCH'
ARCH: Error 19504 Creating archive log file '+DGARCH'
```

I got some suggestions from internet. I should remove archived redo logs that are no longer needed.
Then I would like to do it by RMAN. I executed `RMAN>connect target / as sysdba`. But it said

```
RMAN-00554：initialization of internal recovery manager package failed
RMAN-04005: error from target database
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

I also tried `RMAN>connect target sys/change_on_install`. It didn`t work.

And I checked **sqlnet.ora**.

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH=(TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
ADR_BASE = /grid/grid_base
```

I can use `sys/change_on_install` login sqlplus successfully. What is default password for sys on RMAN?
How can I login RMAN successfully?

Thans in advance!

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? Up to 11g, you connect to RMAN without mentioning the "as sysdba". One other troubleshoot you may try, is to check the ORACLE_SID value.

Comment: I have resolved this problem.  I run rman command as a non-oracle user by mistake. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

hope its been resolved by you as it was asked 2 months before. If you not try the below and update it.

Can you try to connect rman as below,

> rman target /

I believe you are trying with wrong sys account credentials. It worked in sqlplus as you might have tried with "sysdba" role as sqlplus username/password as sysdba.

you can delete all the archivelogs as below,

RMAN>delete archivelog all

Thanks,

Comment: I have resolved this problem.  I run rman command as a non-oracle user by mistake. Thanks for your help.